# How can I get exit code of a twisted spawn process which may be terminated unexpected?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I'm using twisted to spawn a local process, which may be terminated in some condition.

I have a custom `twisted.internet.protocol.ProcessProtocol` class for the reactor. If the local process abruptly terminated, I can't get the return value in `processEnded`. The `exitCode` is set to `None`.

A mcv example is like this:

```
from twisted.internet import error,protocol,reactor

class MyPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def processEnded(self, reason):
        if reason.check(error.ProcessTerminated):
            err_info = "wrong termination: %s; exitCode: %s; signal: %s" % \
                        (reason, reason.value.exitCode, reason.value.signal)
            print(err_info)
        else:
            print("processEnded, status %d" % (reason.value.exitCode,))
            print("quitting")
        reactor.stop()

pp = MyPP()
reactor.spawnProcess(pp, "throw_exception", ["throw_exception"], {})
reactor.run()
```

And the `throw_exception` executable could be compiled from:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    throw std::runtime_error("some exception");
    return 0;
}
```

Execute the python example will print

> wrong termination: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no
>   frames): : A process
>   has ended with a probable error condition: process ended by signal 6.
>   ]; **exitCode: None**; signal: 6

The C++ example will have a return value of 134 if run in a shell, which means `SIGABRT`(6) sent. (I've also tested sending `SIGINT` to terminate and still getting no exit code.)

How can I get it in the `ProcessProtocal` instance? Or it is impossible?

Comment: So ... you want 134 instead of 6?  Or what?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I'd like to get 134 or any other return value in that twisted process protocol instance, instead of the `None` in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, 134 is the "wait status" (or, in the man pages, the "wstatus").  It encodes a few pieces of information about a running-state-transition the process being `wait()` on underwent.

The possible transitions are:

- exited with a code (ie, called `exit(2)`)
- was killed by a signal
- whether a core dump was produced
- was stopped (eg by `SIGSTOP`)
- was un-stopped (eg with `SIGCONT`)

POSIX provides macros for extracting the details from the wait status: `WIFEXITED`, `WIFSIGNALED`, `WTERMSIG`, `WEXITSTATUS`, etc.

Python exposes these through the `os` module: `os.WIFEXITED`, etc.

`os.WIFEXITED(134)` evaluates to `False`.  `os.WIFSIGNALED(134)` evaluates to true and `os.WTERMSIG(134)` evaluates to `6`.

`ProcessDone` and `ProcessTerminated` use these macros to extract the information and present it in a slightly more useful form - the `exitCode` and `signal` attributes.

POSIX doesn't provide a way to go the *other* way, though.  There's no standard API for constructing a "wait status" representing, say, "the process was killed by signal 6".

Fortunately, partially because there's no way to go backwards, Twisted preserves the original wait status on the exception as the `status` attribute.  If you check that attribute on the exception wrapped in the `Failure` passed to your `ProcessProtocol`, you should find the wait status you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I found it in as an attribute of `ProcessTerminated` class at last. It's a platform specific value and I always get a `6` on my mac, which cause lots of confusion until testing it on my linux server and getting 134 eventually.

Comment: Yea, that platform-specificness is why it's usually a better idea to use `exitCode` and `signal`. :)